# Changing the controller number of of nvme devices

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, linux-kernel, nvme

Is there a method of changing the nvme controller ID. So for example turning nvme3n1 into nvme1n1. I've noticed the controllerID usually increments after removing and adding the device, but I'd like to either reduce it or keep it the same. In my mind this would be an echo to something in /sys but I'm yet to find anything useful. This is consistently resolved following a reboot, so I assume there's a call I can make to reset/change it?

I was hoping this would work, but even if I rescan the specific pci bus it still fails:

```
echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/$(readlink -f /sys/class/nvme/nvme2 | awk -F "/" '{print $5}')/remove
echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/$(readlink -f /sys/class/nvme/nvme1 | awk -F "/" '{print $5}')/remove
echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/rescan
```

Thanks guys

Comment: Please edit your Q to include your best attempt to code a solution for this problem. Readers can't help fix what they can't see. Good luck!

Comment: Can you use the persistent storage links under /dev/disk/by-id/ instead of the raw device names?

Comment: @IanAbbott Yes, that could work.. I'm not really sure what I should be hitting/changing though? I've just done a grep in these folders for the device ID but not found it.

Comment: @shellter I've added some examples of what I've tried (admittedly not a lot). In this instance I was trying to swap the disk allocations rounds (so nvme2 becomes nvme1).

Comment: Well the files under /dev/disk/by-id/ are just symbolic links to the devices in /dev/ so you should be able to match them up by reading the links. They have persistent names, so even if the controller number changes the symbolic link name should stay the same.

Comment: Good show! Any code is better than nothing, and NOW I can see that I can't help on this one (although your code looks reasonable). I hope Ian's ideas are helping. Good luck!

Comment: I've got code which reads the capacity of a block device (puppet fact) to decide whether to expand the disk. This works fine unless the nvme devices are wrong when first run. I get failures relating to capacity after reboot. Essentially my server boots with devices in the "wrong" order 90% of the time, I automate disk capacity and then reboot at which point it's wrecked when trying to expand a disk. The current fix is reboot before running any code. Nvme uses the order it's attached in to decide the name; which is crap for automation tools which have no set order such as terraform.

Comment: Using disk device names has always had this problem.  The fix is to use persistent names: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Persistent_block_device_naming

Comment: @stark they change on boot, it's slightly odd behaviour. Basically we run some commands to attach the device to lvm before rebooting, then at the moment of reboot the devices switch round.